# Bourbaki - Algebra Chapter IV - Section 6, Exercise 9(b)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $S_i(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ be the elementary symmetric functions in the variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$.
Let $r_1,r_2,\dots,r_n$ be $n$ rational functions in the $X_1,\dots,X_n$. Let $T$ be a variable different from $X_1,\dots,X_n$. Let
$$\frac{1+r_1T + r_2T^2 + \cdots +r_nT^n}{1+S_1T+S_2T^2+\cdots+S_nT^n} =
           1 + u_1T + u_2T^2 + \cdots$$
where the $u_1,u_2,\ldots$ are rational functions of $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$.
If at least $n$ of the $u_j = 0$, show that the $r_i = S_i$. 
I can do this if it is assumed that the $u_j=0$ have subscript $j \geq n$ but I'm stuck in the case that one or more of the $j$ are $< n$.